# The request is not included in the custom filter. Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-filter

Hello everyone I am writing Authentication using Spring Security and JWT tokens.

I add my own filter in the configuration. But the request is not included in the filter. Therefore, all requests to any address are executed, even without a token.

**SecurityConfig.class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("my.pac")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtFilter jwtFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register", "/auth").permitAll()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

**Filter**

```
@Component
public class JwtFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    public static final String AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";

    @Autowired
    private JwtProvider jwtProvider;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.info("do filter...");
        String token = getTokenFromRequest((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);
        if (token != null && jwtProvider.validateToken(token)) {
            String userLogin = jwtProvider.getLoginFromToken(token);
            CustomUserDetails customUserDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userLogin);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(customUserDetails, null, customUserDetails.getAuthorities());
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    private String getTokenFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearer = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
        if (hasText(bearer) && bearer.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearer.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }}
```

**upd:**

this option also does not work for the filter:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register", "/auth").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Comment: you dont need a custom jwtfilter as spring security already has a included jwtfilter that you can customize. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture

Answer (score 0):

You only specified `.antMatchers("/register", "/auth").permitAll()`, to force authentication to other things you must add `.anyRequest().authenticated()`
So something like this

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/register", "/auth").permitAll()
            .and()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also added this, but the filter does not catch the request((

Comment: Maybe some other filter that is before your filter already breaks the chain? Are you sure that UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is invoked and your filter is not?

Comment: how to check it?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and see if your code stops. Your filter should be before so if it reaches UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter something must be still wrong with the config

Comment: I set the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter breakpoint and the program does not stop there. what could be the problem?

Comment: all the examples that I find are made via Boot. I do everything according to the example and it doesn't work for me. Can there be some kind of automatic setup on boot that doesn't exist without boot?